# Get the number of instantiated objects in Java

Tags: java

```
class Clasa {...}

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Clasa x = new Clasa();
        System.out.println(x.getNo());//displays 1
        Clasa[] y = new Clasa[10];
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
            y[i]=new Clasa();
        System.out.println(y[0].getNo()); //displays 5
    }
}
```

How can I replace those three dots, so GetNo() method call to return the number of instantiated objects of class Clasa. Test class should not be changed.

Comment: @hexafraction: Why on Earth would you use reflection for this? (And, for that matter -- *how* on Earth would you use reflection for this?)

Comment: Try some logic, and if it doesn't work then ask for help. Try not to ask for logic or code directly.

Comment: @hexafraction He doesn't want all java instances only `number of instantiated objects of class Clasa`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Brian , on that the above code is not considering the GC. So I would like to replace your code with the below code snippet

```
package com.instance.main;
import com.instance.target.Clasa;

    public class Test{

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Clasa targetClass;
        Object[] object=new Object[10];
        for(int i=0;i<object.length;i++){
            object[i]=new Clasa();
        }

        System.out.println("Number of Instantiate Object {Before Calling GC}: "+Clasa .getNumberOfInstatiateObj());

        /* Here I am trying to deallocate the memory of Object at index no 9, so that GC   called this unused object to deallocate it from memory*/
        for(int i=0;i<object.length;i++){
            if(i==8){
                object[i]=object[i+1];
                object[i+1]=null;
                System.runFinalization();
                System.gc();
            }
        }   

        }
    }
```

just put the above code beneath the main method and also you have to modify your Clasa code from the below code

package com.instance.target;

class Clasa {

```
    private static int nbInstances = 0;

    public Clasa () {
        nbInstances++;
    }

    public int getNo() {
        return nbInstances;
    }

  public void finalize(){
      nbInstances --;
      System.out.println("Number of Instantiate Object {After Calling GC}: "+nbInstances );
  }
```

}

After modifying your code by following the above steps , your code will give you your desired output.

Please let me correct if I am wrong some where.

Hi Dany I modified my code , so according to the above code ,you have to create your class under different package which written in the class code . And let me know if you are getting problem still.

Comment: I do not agree with you :)
He is obviously a beginner in Java. He should learn it step by step. Whereas your code has soo many advanced features of Java, it would scare him ..

Comment: Also, The way you put your solution does not help him because you are telling him to use the code as is without even knowing what it does

Comment: @Adel , ya you are right I didn't give much information on the above code.

Comment: @Dany , Dany as you know that GC called the finalize method to close the resources that may be used by the object. This call is done internally , so you can override the finalize method and decrease your counter.

Comment: @Ashish Thx for your complex answer, I like more the GC approach, unfortunately I could not make it run, I'm still working at this.

Comment: @Dany, Thanks, May I know where you are getting problem to run the above code.

Comment: @Ashish the maine method is in Test class and as I sad before the Test class should not be changed,but I don't care about this aspect, I want to learn the concept. I have problems putting all the parts from your code together. Thx for all your help.

Comment: @Danny , I modified my code , please have a look for modification I done.I hope that will help you to run the program.

Comment: @Ashish you are awesome, thx. I've chanced "+Clasa .getNumberOfInstatiateObj())" to +Clasa.getNo()) because getNumberOfInstatiateObj() wasn't defined in class Clasa and it works. I've got this output: Number of Instantiate Object {Before Calling GC}: 10
Number of Instantiate Object {After Calling GC}: 9

Comment: @Danny,thnkx, and I am really glad to know that my code worked for you.Enjoy your learning :).

Answer (score 4):

Add a static variable which acts as a counter and increment it inside the constructor and `getNo` returns the value of the static variable.

Static variable have their values kept across all instances of a class

```
class Clasa {

    private static int nbInstances = 0;

    public Clasa () {
        nbInstances++;
    }

    public int getNo() {
        return nbInstances;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that it's not threadsafe and of course won't decrement when an object gets GC'd.

Comment: @BrianRoach From his code and question, I don't think he cares about GC and decrementing

Comment: I agree that *he* doesn't care, as he's just getting you to do his homework for him ;) However, someone else searching for an answer to this topic might, hence my comment.

Comment: @BrianRoach You'd be amazed at the number of duplicated questions anywhere! Otherwise, I totally agree :)

Comment: Sorry for this, is not my homework I'm trying to do a test,because I want to learn Java better, I tried to find the answer here.